# Change string font size in webresource Javascript CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, crm, font-size

I'm trying to do the next but I don't know if is possible develop that:

I have two strings like;

```
var str1 = "Hello"; var str2 = "world";
```

And I change the description of an e-mail like this:

```
Name.SetValue(str1.concat(str2));
```

I need `str2` be smaller of font size than `str1`. I have tried with `style.fontsize, str2.fontSize(7)` .. and are not working..

any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
var html = '<FONT size=1 face="Tahoma"> <P><FONT size=2><P><br></br>Hello</P><P>World</P>  </FONT><P>Hello 2<P/>\"World\"</P></FONT>';

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue(html.toString());
```

Note: The second string world is written inside ""